# Zero or more length of path in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, path, cypher

For example I have a path:

```
1-[:A]->2-[:B]->3
```

And we can use the * operator to define if a particular edge can be repeated. I would like to use the * operator on the entire path, or both edges combined. I would like to follow: (A AND B) zero or more times.

Example:

```
1-[:A]->2-[:B]->3-[:A]->4-[:B]->5...
```

I am not sure how to apply the * operator for the entire path in Cypher. My intent is to express a pattern that allows a specific path to be repeated 0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

This is something variable-length patterns cannot do in Cypher. However, because of this, we added repeating sequences functionality to [path expander procs in APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths).

As an example:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = 123
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {relationshipFilter:'A>, B>'}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

This expands from a start node (`n`) expanding out only a repeating sequence of outgoing :A and :B relationships. No minLevel or maxLevel properties were provided, so this has a minimum of 0 length and no bounds on max length.